# Interactive Brokers: Looking for asset classes similar to stock market that I can practice buy/sell outside business hours

Tags: interactive-brokers

I am in EST Timezone and I work during the business hours.

I am trying to practice trading using IB's Trading Workstation. I have Trading Workstation installed on my machine and I've a practice account.

The challenge that I am going through is that I can't experience market buy/sell orders outside market hours.

Do we have asset classes similar to stock market that I can practice buy/sell trades outside business hours?

Comment: asian markets ??

Comment: @Fattie, wow, that is good idea. Where do I get the list of markets that we can trade on IB?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea about that!  Pls ask a new question !

Comment: Not answering your question but a well meant  personal recommendation is to trade as little as possible unless you like gambling and don't mind losses. Simply buying a few cheap (low fee) ETFs will not only save you valuable time but also earn you a lot more money than trading. See for example [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/155284/109107) for the performance of professional investors with millions of resources and plenty of smart people.

Comment: @AKdemy, trading is gabling indeed when the trader has no proper education. The problem is that Youtube makes people believe  that can look at some indicators on a technical charts, buy/sell and make money. As you said, that warrants loss of money. If there was a "certified trader exam", only 5% of trader hopefuls would pass. .....

Comment: ... The problem is there is no such exam or gate.   Trading is VERY profitable profession when there is a proper education (no the ones advertised on Youtube) is behind it. That applies any profitable profession to be honest. It does takes at least 2-3 years of full-time hard study to become an entry level trader.

Comment: For what its worth, there are certified trader exams and in most jurisdictions you need to pass them before being able to actually trade on an institutional level....

Comment: Yes, but my point is that anybody is allowed to buy/sell in the market without much of warning, Oh well....

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing on the US equity markets that I know of that consistently trades with sufficient liquidity during after hours.

[TD Ameritrade](https://tickertape.tdameritrade.com/tools/backtest-historical-data-thinkorswimondemand-15667) offers a backtesting simulator that allows you to go back in time and trade going forward.

I don't know what it takes to access it (free?) but it might suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for help. The idea is to build expertise on "Trading Workstation". I've used other platforms on US equities. The idea here is to do in-depth learning of "Trading Workstation" during evenings when I am off work.

Comment: "I don't know what it takes to access it (free?) but it might suit your needs." — Yes, the "OnDemand" feature is free on TD Ameritrade's free thinkorswim trading platform.